# Can i access JNDI from a junit class from a server?

Tags: java, jndi

Can I do a JNDI lookup from a standalone class from a server running in a different JVM ?

Comment: What JNDI implementation are you using?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can. check you application  server for params.

```
Properties p =new Properties();
//add properties specific to your server
Context ctx = new InitialContext(p);
FooBean fooBean = (FooBean) ctx.lookup("/foo/fooBean");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you will need to configure JNDI in the JVM running the tests, so that it knows to contact the server's JVM. How you do that depends entirely on what JNDI implementation you are using.